# Why did no one come for the Zeo Crystal for 65 million years?

Tags: power-rangers, power-rangers-2017

Again, a *Power Rangers* (2017) question.

We are told (by both Zordon and Rita) that there are forces in the Universe who want to possess the Zeo Crystal.

Thus the Rangers' main mission is to protect it.

But when the previous team died and Rita got blown into the sea, there was no one left on Earth to protect the Crystal until the new team was formed in modern times.

Are we supposed to believe that no one came for the Crystal for 65 million years? No one wanted it except for Rita? Why?

Comment: Because terrible writing.

Answer (score 1):

We know from Zordon's exposition that his was far from the only Ranger team.  We also know that every planet which has life has a piece of the Crystal.

It's highly likely that Earth is simply out-of-the-way and most people who want to seize a piece of the Crystal attempt to reach ones that are easier to get to (on their own planet, perhaps, or on one nearer than Earth).

It's also possible that the remaining Ranger teams off of Earth are just doing a really good job of stopping evil - perhaps anyone who heads in the direction of Earth is stopped well short of the planet?  Perhaps Earth is not hard for the greater galactic community to find/reach, but is easily defended from space?  Maybe there's a significant Ranger presence in nearby systems, which serves to protect Earth from invasion (but not Rita, who is already here).

Comment: Possibly S.P.D.?